# (B,N) pair and Steinberg idempotent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

Let $q=p^f$ where $p$ is prime and $G$ be a finite group with a $(B,N)−$pair ($T=B\cap N$ and $W=N/T$), and assume that $B=UT$ with $U\triangleleft B$ and $U\cap T=1$. Define $$e=\dfrac{1}{[G:U]}\underline{b}\underline{w}\in \mathbb{F}_q[G]$$
with $$\underline{b}=\dfrac{1}{|B|}\sum\limits_{b\in B}b,\underline{w}=\dfrac{1}{|W|}\sum\limits_{w\in W}\varepsilon(w)w$$
where $\varepsilon(w)=(-1)^{l(w)}$ and $l(w)$ is the length function i.e. the number of generators of $W$ needed to write $w$.

Is it the so-called the Steinberg idempotent ? (I have seen it for $GL(n,q)$ but not for the more general setting of groups with a $(B,N)-$pair).

How do we prove it is an idempotent of $\mathbb{F}_q[G]$?